# command option gets ignored in docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

These are the contents of my docker-compose.yaml.

```
rabbitmq:
  image: docker_rabbitmq
  hostname: rabbitmq
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"

elasticsearch:
  image: docker_elasticsearch
  hostname: elasticsearch
  restart: always

ui-console:
  image: docker-ui-console
  hostname: ui-console
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
    - "3443:3443"
  command: bash -c "node ui-configurator.js -f  configure-ui.yaml"
```

But the command option gets ignored. I want to execute the "node ui-configurator.js -f  configure-ui.yaml" on container startup.
Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: I tried entrypoint.sh but need to share the entrypoint.sh using volumes which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could run node in command directly, without wrapping with bash -c, such as

```
  command: node ui-configurator.js -f configure-ui.yaml
```

As long as you make sure WORKDIR is correct so ui-configurator.js and configure-ui.yaml can be found, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
command: [ "node", "ui-configurator.js", "-f", "configure-ui.yaml" ]
```